# XPath like query for nested python dictionaries

Tags: python, xpath, jmespath, json-path-expression

Is there a way to define a XPath type query for nested python dictionaries.

Something like this:

```
foo = {
  'spam':'eggs',
  'morefoo': {
               'bar':'soap',
               'morebar': {'bacon' : 'foobar'}
              }
   }

print( foo.select("/morefoo/morebar") )

>> {'bacon' : 'foobar'}
```

I also needed to select nested lists ;)

This can be done easily with @jellybean's solution:

```
def xpath_get(mydict, path):
    elem = mydict
    try:
        for x in path.strip("/").split("/"):
            try:
                x = int(x)
                elem = elem[x]
            except ValueError:
                elem = elem.get(x)
    except:
        pass

    return elem

foo = {
  'spam':'eggs',
  'morefoo': [{
               'bar':'soap',
               'morebar': {
                           'bacon' : {
                                       'bla':'balbla'
                                     }
                           }
              },
              'bla'
              ]
   }

print xpath_get(foo, "/morefoo/0/morebar/bacon")
```

[EDIT 2016] This question and the accepted answer are ancient. The newer answers may do the job better than the original answer. However I did not test them so I won't change the accepted answer.

Comment: Why not using `foo['morefoo']['morebar']` ?

Comment: because I want to do: def bla(query): data.select(query)

Comment: @MarcoS It would be more interesting with lists where the path microlanguage would return multiple items.

Comment: @PavelŠimerda Yes, way more interesting, especially with wildcard queries  (find all values under a specific key), and then - also recurse down lists or [named]tuples...

Comment: This question (in Python) essentially asks for a recommendation of a 3rd party library.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Not exactly beautiful, but you might use sth like

```
def xpath_get(mydict, path):
    elem = mydict
    try:
        for x in path.strip("/").split("/"):
            elem = elem.get(x)
    except:
        pass

    return elem
```

This doesn't support xpath stuff like indices, of course ... not to mention the `/` key trap unutbu indicated.

Comment: In 2011 maybe there weren't as many options as there are today, but in 2014, I think, solving the problem this way is not elegant and should be avoided.

Comment: @nikolay is this just a guess or are there solutions that solve this more nicely?

Answer (score 22):

One of the best libraries I've been able to identify, which, in addition, is very actively developed, is an extracted project from boto: [JMESPath](https://jmespath.readthedocs.org/en/latest/). It has a very powerful syntax of doing things that would normally take pages of code to express.

Here are some examples:

```
search('foo | bar', {"foo": {"bar": "baz"}}) -> "baz"
search('foo[*].bar | [0]', {
    "foo": [{"bar": ["first1", "second1"]},
            {"bar": ["first2", "second2"]}]}) -> ["first1", "second1"]
search('foo | [0]', {"foo": [0, 1, 2]}) -> [0]
```

Comment: but this does not allow to modify the dict :(

Answer (score 19):

There is an easier way to do this now.

http://github.com/akesterson/dpath-python

```
$ easy_install dpath
>>> dpath.util.search(YOUR_DICTIONARY, "morefoo/morebar")
```

... done. Or if you don't like getting your results back in a view (merged dictionary that retains the paths), yield them instead:

```
$ easy_install dpath
>>> for (path, value) in dpath.util.search(YOUR_DICTIONARY, "morefoo/morebar", yielded=True)
```

... and done. 'value' will hold {'bacon': 'foobar'} in that case.

Comment: The iterated statement doesn't run---there's no body to the for statement.

Answer (score 14):

There is the newer [jsonpath-rw](https://github.com/kennknowles/python-jsonpath-rw) library supporting a [JSONPATH](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/jsonpath) syntax but for python *dictionaries* and *arrays*, as you wished.

So your 1st example becomes:

```
from jsonpath_rw import parse

print( parse('$.morefoo.morebar').find(foo) )
```

And the 2nd:

```
print( parse("$.morefoo[0].morebar.bacon").find(foo) )
```

---

PS: An alternative simpler library also supporting dictionaries is [python-json-pointer](https://github.com/stefankoegl/python-json-pointer/blob/master/doc/tutorial.rst) with a more XPath-like syntax.

Comment: Note that jsonpath uses eval and jsonpath-rw looks unmaintained (it also says some features are missing, but I haven't tried it).

Answer (score 10):

### dict > jmespath

You can use [JMESPath](http://jmespath.org/) which is a query language for JSON, and which has a [python implementation](https://github.com/jmespath/jmespath.py).

```python
import jmespath # pip install jmespath

data = {'root': {'section': {'item1': 'value1', 'item2': 'value2'}}}

jmespath.search('root.section.item2', data)
Out[42]: 'value2'
```

The jmespath query syntax and live examples: http://jmespath.org/tutorial.html

### dict > xml > xpath

Another option would be converting your dictionaries to XML using something like [dicttoxml](https://github.com/quandyfactory/dicttoxml) and then use regular XPath expressions e.g. via [lxml](https://lxml.de/) or whatever other library you prefer.

```python
from dicttoxml import dicttoxml  # pip install dicttoxml
from lxml import etree  # pip install lxml

data = {'root': {'section': {'item1': 'value1', 'item2': 'value2'}}}
xml_data = dicttoxml(data, attr_type=False)
Out[43]: b'<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?><root><root><section><item1>value1</item1><item2>value2</item2></section></root></root>'

tree = etree.fromstring(xml_data)
tree.xpath('//item2/text()')
Out[44]: ['value2']
```

### Json Pointer

Yet another option is [Json Pointer](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6901) which is an [IETF spec](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6901) that has a python implementation:

- https://github.com/stefankoegl/python-json-pointer

From the [jsonpointer-python tutorial](https://python-json-pointer.readthedocs.io/en/latest/tutorial.html):

```python
from jsonpointer import resolve_pointer

obj = {"foo": {"anArray": [ {"prop": 44}], "another prop": {"baz": "A string" }}}

resolve_pointer(obj, '') == obj
# True

resolve_pointer(obj, '/foo/another%20prop/baz') == obj['foo']['another prop']['baz']
# True

>>> resolve_pointer(obj, '/foo/anArray/0') == obj['foo']['anArray'][0]
# True
```

Comment: checking this, as I wouldn't want to change backend API, but to traverse the output json

Comment: Converting from dict to xml and than using path doesn't seem to me as good practise.

Answer (score 5):

If terseness is your fancy:

```
def xpath(root, path, sch='/'):
    return reduce(lambda acc, nxt: acc[nxt],
                  [int(x) if x.isdigit() else x for x in path.split(sch)],
                  root)
```

Of course, if you *only* have dicts, then it's simpler:

```
def xpath(root, path, sch='/'):
    return reduce(lambda acc, nxt: acc[nxt],
                  path.split(sch),
                  root)
```

Good luck finding any errors in your path spec tho ;-)

Comment: This will avoid converting things to ints if a node is a dict:  def xpath(root, path, sep='/'): return reduce(lambda node, key: node[key if hasattr(node, 'keys') else int(key)], path.split(sep), root)

Comment: Cool solution. For Python 3, need `from functools import reduce` though.

Comment: I like this *terseness*  -  the parser should give a `key not found` error when the path spec is wrong, so that should not be very painful to debug.

Comment: great solution, but breaks when you have a dictionary key as an integer, e.g. in `d1 = {'a': {'1': {'c': {'d': {'e': 2}}}}, 'c': {'e': {}}}`

Comment: Of course, it is impossible to distinguish when to key into a list or key into a dictionary without introducing more syntax to the xquery logic.

Answer (score 2):

More work would have to be put into how the XPath-like selector would work.
`'/'` is a valid dictionary key, so how would

```
foo={'/':{'/':'eggs'},'//':'ham'}
```

be handled?

```
foo.select("///")
```

would be ambiguous.

Comment: Yes, you would need a parser for that. But what I am asking is for a xpath _like_ method. "morefoo.morebar" is fine by me.

Comment: @RickyA: `'.'` is also a value dictionary key. The same problem would exist. `foo.select('...')` would be ambiguous.

Answer (score 2):

Another alternative (besides that suggested by [jellybean](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7320319/xpath-like-query-for-nested-python-dictionaries/7320664#7320664)) is this:

```
def querydict(d, q):
  keys = q.split('/')
  nd = d
  for k in keys:
    if k == '':
      continue
    if k in nd:
      nd = nd[k]
    else:
      return None
  return nd

foo = {
  'spam':'eggs',
  'morefoo': {
               'bar':'soap',
               'morebar': {'bacon' : 'foobar'}
              }
   }
print querydict(foo, "/morefoo/morebar")
```

Comment: this should be the solution

Answer (score 1):

Is there any reason for you to the query it the way like the XPath pattern? As the commenter to your question suggested, it just a dictionary, so you can access the elements in a nest manner. Also, considering that data is in the form of JSON, you can use simplejson module to load it and access the elements too.

There is this project [JSONPATH](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/jsonpath), which is trying to help people do opposite of what you intend to do (given an XPATH, how to make it easily accessible via python objects), which seems more useful.

Comment: The reason is that I want to split the data and the query. I want to be flexible in the query part. If I access it the nested way the query is hardcoded in the program.

Comment: @RickyA, in the other comment you say morefoo.morebar is fine. Did you check the JSONPATH project (Download and look at the source and tests).

Comment: I did take a look at JSONPATH, but my input is not text/json. It's nested dictionaries.

Comment: @RickyA's question is super valuable when using mongodb, for example. If you want to iterate over nested keys in a BSON document, this is necessary.

Answer (score 0):

```
def Dict(var, *arg, **kwarg):
  """ Return the value of an (imbricated) dictionnary, if all fields exist else return "" unless "default=new_value" specified as end argument
      Avoid TypeError: argument of type 'NoneType' is not iterable
      Ex: Dict(variable_dict, 'field1', 'field2', default = 0)
  """
  for key in arg:
    if isinstance(var, dict) and key and key in var:  var = var[key]
    else:  return kwarg['default'] if kwarg and 'default' in kwarg else ""   # Allow Dict(var, tvdbid).isdigit() for example
  return kwarg['default'] if var in (None, '', 'N/A', 'null') and kwarg and 'default' in kwarg else "" if var in (None, '', 'N/A', 'null') else var

foo = {
  'spam':'eggs',
  'morefoo': {
               'bar':'soap',
               'morebar': {'bacon' : 'foobar'}
              }
   }
print Dict(foo, 'morefoo', 'morebar')
print Dict(foo, 'morefoo', 'morebar', default=None)
```

Have a SaveDict(value, var, *arg) function that can even append to lists in dict...

Answer (score 0):

I reference form this [link.](https://programmerall.com/article/1002730873/).

Following code is for json xpath base parse implemented in python :

```
import json
import xmltodict

# Parse the json string
class jsonprase(object):
    def __init__(self, json_value):
        try:
            self.json_value = json.loads(json_value)
        except Exception :
            raise ValueError('must be a json str value')


    def find_json_node_by_xpath(self, xpath):
        elem = self.json_value
        nodes = xpath.strip("/").split("/")
        for x in range(len(nodes)):
            try:
                elem = elem.get(nodes[x])
            except AttributeError:
                elem = [y.get(nodes[x]) for y in elem]
        return elem

    def datalength(self, xpath="/"):
        return len(self.find_json_node_by_xpath(xpath))

    @property
    def json_to_xml(self):
        try:
            root = {"root": self.json_value}
            xml = xmltodict.unparse(root, pretty=True)
        except ArithmeticError :
            pyapilog().error(e)
        return xml
```

Test Json :

```
{
    "responseHeader": {
        "zkConnected": true,
        "status": 0,
        "QTime": 2675,
        "params": {
            "q": "TxnInitTime:[2021-11-01T00:00:00Z TO 2021-11-30T23:59:59Z] AND Status:6",
            "stats": "on",
            "stats.facet": "CountryCode",
            "rows": "0",
            "wt": "json",
            "stats.field": "ItemPrice"
        }
    },
    "response": {
        "numFound": 15162439,
        "start": 0,
        "maxScore": 1.8660598,
        "docs": []
    }
}
```

**Test Code to read the values from above input json.**

```
numFound = jsonprase(ABOVE_INPUT_JSON).find_json_node_by_xpath('/response/numFound')
print(numFound)
```