# iteration through nested dictionaries

Tags: python, dictionary

I'm trying to implement simple tree class which is inherited from dictionary. 
Here my code:

```
class tree(dict):
    def __init__(self, hsymbol="/"):
        self.hsymbol = hsymbol
    def __setitem__(self, key, value):
        if key[0] == self.hsymbol : key = key[1:]
        parts = key.split(self.hsymbol, 1)
        if len(parts) == 2:
            if parts[0] not in self: self[parts[0]] = tree(hsymbol = self.hsymbol)
            self[parts[0]].__setitem__(parts[1], value)
        else:
            super(tree, self).__setitem__(key, value)

    def __getitem__(self, key):
        if key[0] == self.hsymbol : key = key[1:]
        parts = key.split(self.hsymbol, 1)
        if len(parts) == 2:
            if parts[0] not in self: raise KeyError(parts[0])
            return self[parts[0]][parts[1]]
        else:
            if key not in self: raise KeyError(parts[0])
            return super(tree, self).__getitem__(key)
    def __contains__(self,key):
        if key[0] == self.hsymbol : key = key[1:]
        parts = key.split(self.hsymbol, 1)
        if len(parts) == 2:
            if not super(tree, self).__contains__(parts[0]): return False
            return parts[1] in self[parts[0]]
        else:
            if not super(tree, self).__contains__(key): return False
            return True
    def __delitem__(self, key):
        if key[0] == self.hsymbol : key = key[1:]
        parts = key.split(self.hsymbol, 1)
        if len(parts) == 2:
            if parts[0] not in self: raise KeyError(parts[0])
            self[parts[0]].__delitem__(parts[1])
        else:
            if key not in list(self): raise KeyError(parts[0])
            super(tree,self).__delitem__(key)
    def keys(self,parent=""):
        #if parent is None: parent = self.hsymbol
        names = []
        for name in super(tree, self).keys():
            if isinstance(self[name], tree):
                names += self[name].keys(parent=parent+self.hsymbol+name)
            else:
                names.append(parent+self.hsymbol+name)
        return names
```

So everything works quite well, although I'm not sure about keys function realization:

```
>>> t=tree()
>>> t['/user/Johnson/incoming'] = 2200
>>> t['/user/Johnson/family'] = 4
>>> t['/user/Johnson/play'] = False
>>> t['/user/Smith/incoming'] = 12000
>>> t['/user/Smith/family'] = 1
>>> t['/user/Smith/play'] = True
>>> t['user/Smith/incoming']
12000    
>>> print t
{'user': {'Smith': {'play': True, 'incoming': 12000, 'family': 1}, 'Johnson': {'play': False, 'incoming': 2200, 'family': 4}}}
>>> print t.keys()
['/user/Smith/play', '/user/Smith/incoming', '/user/Smith/family', '/user/Johnson/play', '/user/Johnson/incoming', '/user/Johnson/family']
>>> t
{'user': {'Smith': {'play': True, 'incoming': 12000, 'family': 1}, 'Johnson': {'play': False, 'incoming': 2200, 'family': 4}}}
```

...but not an iteration through it:

```
>>> for k in t:
...  print k
... 
user
>>>
```

How can I get something like this?

```
/user/Smith/play
/user/Smith/incoming
/user/Smith/family
/user/Johnson/play
/user/Johnson/incoming
/user/Johnson/family
```

Pretty sure that it must be `__iter__` and `next` attributes of tree class, but I haven't figured out how to write it yet.

I've searched over Stack Overflow with no luck:

- python recursive iteration nested dictionaries
- python class inherited from dictionary iteration through nested dictionaries
- python iteration through nested dictionaries

Comment: Complaining about dupehammer holders in the initial rev of a question isn't a good way to set up a... productive working relationship. Keep in mind that if your question *does* get closed, the folks who can reopen it without needing four other voters to agree? Also those with badges. So. **If** your question gets closed with something that you believe isn't a duplicate, argue the case for how it's distinguished at that time; don't set up a hostile position up-front.

Comment: Because you inherit from `dict`, when you iterate over the instance you're calling `dict.__iter__`; your custom `keys` method is ignored. Rather than inheritance, consider *composition*; implement the [`MutableMapping`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.abc.html#collections.abc.MutableMapping) ABC with the wrapped dictionary as an *attribute*. See e.g. http://stackoverflow.com/a/3387975/3001761

Comment: @CharlesDuffy but I'm just tired to ask for example to do something without function, and got that it is duplicate that everything done by functions.... Look a this [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42603914/is-any-way-to-expend-dictionary-notation)....

Comment: Alternatively, implement `__iter__` as `return iter(self.keys())`.

Comment: **If** this question gets closed as a duplicate, **and** if, *after you've actually tried the answers* on the duplicate with appropriate modifications for your specific use case and found they do not solve your problem, **then** edit the question to *clarify specifically how they don't*. There's no guarantee that your question isn't a dupe, and if the dupe has the answer you need why *wouldn't* you want to be shown it?

Comment: I've followed your link, and frankly, I don't think the folks who closed it were acting wrongly. If the title were, say, "Making a single `__getitem__()` recurse", or otherwise explicitly focused on your real goal, then I'd agree. If there were something more concrete describing why function syntax isn't acceptable ("heavier than I want" isn't clear at all -- perhaps a lightweight/clean function would still be fine, then?), maybe then too.

Comment: So. If you edit that question -- without getting hostile -- to be more explicit about what you're looking for (a better question title could be ''supporting dict["item/subitem"] as synonym to dict["item"]["subitem"]'' or such), I might be on-board with its reopening. But as it is, the duplicates look defensible as such.

Comment: that said, even with that edit, the XPath dupe would look like a compelling one. At that point, the only difference is not knowing `__getitem__()` exists -- ie. the remaining aspect of the question that isn't answered is just "how do I override square-bracket dictionary lookup syntax?" or such.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy you are probably right, although XPath answers don't help me with my problem. May be I overestimated a main body of the question, and two direct comments to main question. It doesn't seem correct to close a topic just by title, isn't it?

Comment: @CharlesDuffy but anyway, never mind. I got perfect answers in both cases. I deeply appreciate guys on Stack Overflow who really try to help.

Comment: So -- keep in mind that what we're trying to build here at StackOverflow is a Q&A knowledgebase where folks with a question have a good chance of being redirected by Google &c. to a preexisting canonical answer. To be useful to folks coming from Google, they need to be able to figure out what a question is *about*, and whether it matches their own question, very quickly: That means the title, the excerpt of the question at the top, &c. should be as useful as possible, as opposed to needing to read through the text in detail to decide if the question and its answers will be helpful to them.

Comment: ...so inasmuch as there's a lot of pickiness about being explicit and visible about your question's parameters, that's not just for the benefit of folks who are potentially answering (though it certainly *is* to their benefit), but also for folks with related questions trying to determine whether their actual question has been previously asked, and thus to find a preexisting answer that will suit them.

Comment: Going into SO's historical mission, see https://stackoverflow.blog/2011/01/05/the-wikipedia-of-long-tail-programming-questions/ -- now, notable there, and supportive of your point, is the rule that "it has to be a real duplicate".

Comment: However, since the audience is that long tail, and what we're providing them with is a *really big knowledgebase* to search through, having that knowledgebase be written and edited in such a way as to make it easy to see which answers apply to them is important: A perfect answer hidden in a lot of dupes-that-aren't because someone reading headings from search results can't tell that the one sentence at the end modifies the meaning of everything else isn't a perfect answer.

Comment: ...anyhow, I've tried to edit the other question in a way that clarifies your intent, and responds usefully to the proposed dupes; hopefully it's useful as a template for the future.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy. Appreciate your honest explanations. As a scientists with code in hands, I should say that SO is a good source of ideas how to work around problems. But coding is a tool for me, not a goal. So i do my best to search first and then ask question, only If couldn't find an answer . Thank you for editing, hope it will be useful for other guys.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you need `__iter__` (an iterator will have a `next()` automatically).

Following your existing logic:

```
def __iter__(self, parent=""):
    for name in super(tree, self).keys():
        if isinstance(self[name], tree):
            for item in self[name].__iter__(parent=parent+self.hsymbol+name):
                yield item
        else:
            yield parent+self.hsymbol+name
```

Unlike your current `keys()` implementation, this only walks the tree on an as-needed basis: If a client only needs the first two keys, it only calls `next()` twice, and so the iterator only proceeds past two `yield`s.

(I might suggest implementing `keys` as simply `return list(iter(self))` -- that way you have the lazy approach available for those that want to avoid the inefficiency of unnecessarily walking a full tree, and the non-lazy approach otherwise).

Comment: Thank you! Excellent! It is exactly what I looked for!

Comment: Note that if the OP did use `MutableMapping` it would generate `keys` for them.