# How to parse deeply nested yaml data structures in python

Tags: python, yaml

We have a YAML file which looks somewhat like the following:

```
all:
  children:
    allnetxsites:
      children:
        netxsites:
          hosts:
            bar.:
              ansible_ssh_host: bart.j
              domain: bart.local.domain
              nfs: lars.local.domain
```

How would I go about getting the value `bar.` and the value for the key `nfs`?

Python Code:

```
import yaml
with open("/Users/brendan_vandercar/sites.yaml", 'r') as stream:
    data_loaded = yaml.load(stream)

for element in data_loaded:
    name = "element"['all']['children']['allnetxsites']['children']['netxsites']['hosts']['bart']['nfs'][0]
    print(name)
```

What I would like to get is a list output from this script that has the below:

```
Domain: bart.local.domain
NFS: lars.local.domain
```

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7320319/xpath-like-query-for-nested-python-dictionaries

Answer (score 4):

Your title makes it look like you are a bit confused about what is
going on, or at least about terminology: although "YAML data
structure" might be construed as shorthand for "Python data structure
loaded from a YAML document", you do not further parse that data
structure. Any parsing is done as part of the loading of the YAML
document and parsing is completely finished even before `yaml.load()`
returns. As a result of that loading you have a data structure in Python and
you "just" need to lookup a key in a nested Python data-structure by
recursively walking that data structure.

---

Your YAML example is somewhat uninteresting, as it only represents a
tiny subset of real YAML as your YAML only consists of (plain) scalars
that are strings, mappings, and mapping keys that are scalars.

To walk over that data structure a simplified version of the recursive function @aaaaaa presented
will do:

```
import sys
import yaml

yaml_str = """\
all:
  children:
    allnetxsites:
      children:
        netxsites:
          hosts:
            bar.:
              ansible_ssh_host: bart.j
              domain: bart.local.domain
              nfs: lars.local.domain
"""

data = yaml.safe_load(yaml_str)

def find(key, dictionary):
    # everything is a dict
    for k, v in dictionary.items():
        if k == key:
            yield v
        elif isinstance(v, dict):
            for result in find(key, v):
                yield result

for x in find("nfs", data):
    print(x)
```

which prints the expected:

```
lars.local.domain
```

I have simplified the function `find` because the list handling in the version in the
[snippet](https://gist.github.com/douglasmiranda/5127251) is incorrect.

Although the kinds of scalars used do not affect the recursive lookup,
you probably want a more generic solution that can handle YAML with
(nested) sequences, tagged nodes and complex mapping keys as well.

Assuming your input file to be the slightly more complex `input.yaml`:

```
all:
  {a: x}: !xyz
  - [k, l, 0943]
  children:
    allnetxsites:
      children:
        netxsites:
          hosts:
            bar.:
              ansible_ssh_host: bart.j
              domain: bart.local.domain
              nfs: lars.local.domain
```

You can use `ruamel.yaml` (disclaimer: I am the author of that package) to do:

```
import sys
from pathlib import Path
import ruamel.yaml

in_file = Path('input.yaml')

yaml = ruamel.yaml.YAML()
data = yaml.load(in_file)

def lookup(sk, d, path=[]):
   # lookup the values for key(s) sk return as list the tuple (path to the value, value)
   if isinstance(d, dict):
       for k, v in d.items():
           if k == sk:
               yield (path + [k], v)
           for res in lookup(sk, v, path + [k]):
               yield res
   elif isinstance(d, list):
       for item in d:
           for res in lookup(sk, item, path + [item]):
               yield res

for path, value in lookup("nfs", data):
    print(path, '->', value)
```

which gives:

```
['all', 'children', 'allnetxsites', 'children', 'netxsites', 'hosts', 'bar.', 'nfs'] -> lars.local.domain
```

As PyYAML only parses a subset of YAML 1.1 and loads even less of
that, it cannot handle the valid YAML in `input.yaml`.

The abovementioned snippet, the one @aaaaa is using, is will break on
the loaded YAML because of the (directly) nested sequences/lists

Answer (score 1):

Maybe [this snippet](https://gist.github.com/douglasmiranda/5127251) would provide you some help

```
def find(key, dictionary):
    for k, v in dictionary.iteritems():
        if k == key:
            yield v
        elif isinstance(v, dict):
            for result in find(key, v):
                yield result
        elif isinstance(v, list):
            for d in v:
                for result in find(key, d):
                    yield result
```

Then your code is equivalent to

```
find('nfs', data_loaded)
```

Comment: `.iteritems()` is only available in Python 2 and that is end-of-life next year, use `.items()` instead. Much more problematic is the second class handling of lists, this `find` breaks on directly nested lists, it looks like list was added as an afterthought and incorrectly at that.