# Parse nested dictionary conveniently

Tags: python

What is the best way to index a deeply nested dictionary? Consider the following example:

```py
x = {'a': {'b': {'c': {'d': 1}}}}
item = x['a']['b']['c']['d']
```

Is there a convenient way to provide a path maybe?

```py
# something like this
item = x.get_path('a/b/c/d')
```

Comment: [Xpath like query for nested python dictionaries](https://stackoverflow.com/q/7320319) Pretty old question, though. Sort the answers by date.

Comment: Perfect! That works very nicely.

Comment: accept the answer if it fulfill your requirements.

Comment: Ali: Sorry to post answer and then delete it - I realised after posting recursive implementation that it could be done with a simple loop - now edited and undeleted.

Comment: Note: neither of the answers posted so far support the exact lookup syntax in the question. To do that, you would have to subclass `dict` to add such a lookup method - probably more trouble than it's worth, but possible in principle.

Comment: The accepted answer can be amended to accept the lookup syntax `nested_get('a/b/c/d').split('/'), x)`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can build a *simple* approach, using the built-in library, as below:

```
from functools import reduce, partial
from operator import getitem

nested_get = partial(reduce, getitem)


x = {'a': {'b': {'c': {'d': 1}}}}

item = nested_get(["a", "b", "c", "d"], x)
print(item)
```

**Output**

```
1
```

**UPDATE**

To emulate the behavior of [`dict.get`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#dict.get), use:

```
def nested_get(path, d, default=None):
    current = d
    for key in path:
        try:
            current = current[key]
        except KeyError:
            return default
    return current


x = {'a': {'b': {'c': {'d': 1}}}}

item = nested_get(["a", "b", "c", "d"], x)
print(item)
item = nested_get(["a", "b", "e", "d"], x)
print(item)
```

**Output**

```
1
None
```

Comment: Very nice. Is there a way to provide a None value if the path doesn't exit? A bit like the .get method.

Comment: The updated answer provides a solution to my comment above. Thanks Dani.

Answer (score 2):

Here is a simple implementation that supports approximately the lookup syntax that you are looking for.

```
def get_value(x, path):
    for key in path.split('/'):
        x = x[key]
    return x

x = {'a': {'b': {'c': {'d': 1}}}}

print(get_value(x, 'a/b/c/d'))
```

gives:

```
1
```

If any of the keys do not exist, then you will get an `KeyError`.  If you want some other behaviour (e.g. return `None`) then you could change the `x = x[key]` line to:

```
        try:
            x = x[key]
        except KeyError:
            return None
```